# Unable to fit multiple lines in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to have a Title and multiple lines in a table view cell, however the cell is not expanding for the "title" and the 3 lines to fit in there.

Here is my code that is taking care of the title and the 3 lines

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("deviceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Title"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Line1 " + "\n" + "Line2" + "\n" + "Line3"

    return cell
}
```

This is how it looks after I run the program

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this two new methods It's helps to solve this issues

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your cell height to AutomaticDimention

- Use AutoLayout to set your Label Height

  in your case: you have to set Label height greater than 3 lines of 
  text.
- Set the `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
- `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = YOUR_ESTIMATION_HEIGHT`

then the cell will fit your content